# Comparing negative numbers in JQuery function

Tags: javascript

I am trying to compare two negative numbers and the comparison is failing. In this specific case, `getLeftPercent()` is a negative number (-14) yet when comparing, action B is performed. Logically, (-14) is less than (-10) thus action A should be performed.

If I change the right side comparison operand (-10) to a positive number (1 for example) then action A is performed. Is there some quirk of JavaScript that I'm overlooking (which is staring me in the face)? I can post the complete code but there's not really much more.

```
$(function() {

    // the statement in question
    if (parseInt(getLeftPercent(), 10) < -10) {
        // do action A
        // this is just a debug statement
        $('#posbanner').html('element position is less than negative 10');
    } else {
        // do action B
        // this is just a debug statement
        $('#posbanner').html('element position is greater than  or equal to negative 10');
    }
});

//  element left position on page
function getLeftPercent() {
    var leftStr = $('#sidebar').css('left'),
        pxPos = leftStr.indexOf('px'),
        leftVal = leftStr.substr(0, pxPos),
        leftPercent = (leftVal / $(window).width() * 100).toString(),
        dotPos = leftPercent.indexOf('.'),
        leftPercentStr = dotPos == -1 ? leftPercent  : leftPercent.substr(0, dotPos);
    return leftPercentStr;
};
```

Comment: What is the actual string value returned by `getLeftPercent()` ?

Comment: add `console.log(getLeftPercent())` and check the result in your console (Ctrl+Shift+J in Chrome/Firefox)

Comment: get firebug for FF and debug it step by step, should be able to spot the issue easily

Comment: The actual value returned by getLeftPercent() is a number, which is -14. I've tried debugging with no answer.

Answer (score 2):

I tried running the following code on jsfiddle

```
if (parseInt( -14, 10) < -10)
{
alert("I am in A");
}
else
{
alert("I am in B");
}
```

I get *I am in A*
Not sure, if `getLeftPercent()` is returning the value you expect.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The reason for the $('#posbanner').html ~ statement is to display the actual value returned by getLeftPercent(). It is returning a valid number, but for some reason is not being compared properly

Answer (score 0):

Your `getLeftPercent()` function seems way overcomplicated. I'm not sure whether your "left" is relative to the document or parent element, I'll assume document here.

```
function getLeftPercent() {
    'use strict';
    return ( ($('#sidebar').offset()).left * 100 / $(window).width() );
}
```

Comment: Yes, the function was something that I borrowed from elsewhere. It is a little more than needed but there were other parts that I removed (functionality was more than just returning percentage.

Answer (score -1):

Most likely your substrings return some characters before the number.

```
alert(parseInt('-14abc', 10)); // -14

alert(parseInt('abc-14', 10)); // NaN
```

Comment: The string used in the substring is from $('#sidebar').css('left'), I don't think it would include other extra characters

Comment: The value returned by the function is a number and it does match the positioning of the element on the web page. Thanks